# Oracle VirtualBox VMs are automatically starting at login, but not sure how

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

This may seem like an odd question, but bear with me.

I have inherited the administration of a Windows 2008R2 server on which multiple VirtualBox VMs automatically start at login, but this is no longer required and I cannot figure out what is triggering the VMs to start.

---

#### Places I've looked & things I've checked

- Run `shell:startup`, startup folder is empty
- Nothing in Task Scheduler
- Have looked for Services pertaining to VirtualBox and found nothing
- Have checked `Autostart Enabled` using `vboxmanage.exe showvminfo <VM-Name>` and this is set to `off` for all VMs.
- Virtual Box Virtual Manager Service does not appear to be installed.

**Can anyone suggest where else I should look or what I should check to find out what is causing the VMs to start at login?**

---

*Version info:*

- Oracle VirtualBox 5.2.8 r121009 (Qt5.6.2)
- Windows Server 2008R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I eventually found the answer:

There were a number of entries within the **Startup** section of the **[System Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSConfig)** (`msconfig`) dialog, with the following command string:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm "Virtual Machine Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have Virtual Box Virtual Manager Service installed (usually it is installed on `C:\vms`), it's a very used program to autostart VMs as a service.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/vboxsvc/

https://techgenix.com/start-virtualbox-service/

Comment: Thanks, but no dice - the closest I could fine was an executable called VBoxSVC.exe and a corresponding log file... I'll update my question to include this in the list.